# How do I access observables that belong to a component from a form in the parent viewmodel?

Tags: knockout.js

If I have a knockout view that contain a form made up of several components, how I should I access the values of the component observables when I submit the form? I've been doing something like this:

component foo:

```
function component_vm(params) {
  this.item = params.item || ko.observable();
}
```

in the parent viewmodel:

```
function parent_vm() {
  this.item = ko.observable();
}
```

in the parent view:

```
<form>
  <foo params="item: item"></foo>
</form>
```

This seems kludgy to me. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A first note...**

The mechanism you're using (passing something through `params`) *is* AFAIK the main built-in mechanism to do this.

The first thing you'll have to do is ask yourself *why* this is needed. You haven't shown a *real* case but an abstract repro; chances are that in your real scenario there's a design issue to be solved. I can't quite imagine any specific instance of the abstract scenario you demo (i.e. that a component view model re-uses exactly the observable from its parent), are you sure you're not breaking encapsulation?

One typical thing where I *do* think a link between components and its parent makes sense is when the parent's (computed) observables differ based on its children. You could consider using [ko-postbox](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox) for this, or manually do pub-sub like so:

```
function component_vm(params) {
  this.item = ko.observable();
  if (!!params.itemChangedHandler) {
    this.item.subscribe(params.itemChangedHandler);
  }
}

function parent_vm() {
  this.someHandler = function() {
    alert('Parent knows something is up!');
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <foo params="itemChangedHandler: someHandler "></foo>
</form>
```

---

**A second note...**

I typically like components to be self-contained (as you might have gathered from my earlier suggestion to use something like ko-postbox for inter-component comms). My components typically have their own "tasks" for the user and their own unit of work associated with it.

Don't forget that KnockoutJS also supports the [`template` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html), because it sounds to me (at least from your comment to this answer) that the child "components" actually are *required* for the parent to work properly, and in that case I recommend using templates instead for modularizing your app and making your code more reuseable.

```js
// Mock ajax calls:
var $ = { post: function(url, dto) { console.log(dto); } };

function Address() {
  this.addressLine1 = ko.observable();
  this.addressLine2 = ko.observable();
  this.addressLine3 = ko.observable();
}

function Person() {
  this.firstName = ko.observable();
  this.lastName = ko.observable();
  this.mainAddress = new Address();
  this.secondaryAddress = new Address();
}

function RootVm() {
  var self = this;
  self.person = new Person();
  self.submit = function() {
    $.post("my_url", ko.toJSON(self.person));
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new RootVm());
```

```css
div { margin: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/html" id="addressTmpl">
  <input data-bind="textInput: addressLine1" placeholder="address line 1"><br>
  <input data-bind="textInput: addressLine2" placeholder="address line 2"><br>
  <input data-bind="textInput: addressLine3" placeholder="address line 3">
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="personTmpl">
  Name:
  <div>
    <input data-bind="textInput: firstName" placeholder="firstname">
    <input data-bind="textInput: lastName" placeholder="surname">
  </div>
  Main address: <div data-bind="template: { name: 'addressTmpl', data: mainAddress }"></div>
  Secondary address: <div data-bind="template: { name: 'addressTmpl', data: secondaryAddress }"></div>
</script>

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'personTmpl', data: person }"></div>
<button data-bind="click: submit">submit</button>
```

---

**A final note...**

If you *really* want to have a hard link between the two view models, and dislike the above two options / insist on using `component`s, then I second the suggestion in [@Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36595678/419956) and use a [`createViewModel` factory function](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html#a-createviewmodel-factory-function).

The details would be specific to your actual situation / app, but you can give that function access to the parent either through a means in your own app, or the `contextFor` suggestion in the other answer.

Comment: We have a pattern that instantiates a page and all it's containing components. There's a root that is the entire page, then a list of components. Typically, we have several panel components with each panel containing child components (which may contain their own components). In order to submit the form, I need to gather all of the form values from each component, unless you can think of a better way :)

Comment: @MusicalShore I understand. In that case you should consider mixing a use of components and templates, see my updated answer. At any rate, getting a tight coupling between view models of seperate components through something besides params is (probably intentionally) difficult, since components are meant to be *de*-coupled.

Comment: Ideally, the components aren't needed for the parent to run properly. The root viewmodel just instantiates a root "dashboard" component that renders all of its child components that are described in a template. In my case, I have kludge surrounding the root component that binds observables to the components. @Andrew's solution is too tightly coupled. I'm not sure how I'd implement the template solution, given the complexity of the components. I like the postbox method, but would I need to publish a separate topic for each observable? That almost seems the same as my original solution.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need a peer and a whiteboard to work on your front-end architecture. Which tool or part of KO is best for your app is impossible to discuss on SO I'm afraid. The question you asked is what I've tried to answer, but from what I get from your comments you'll need broader help, which I can't offer, sorry. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can directly access the parent context by using a createViewModel factory function, so instead of this:

```
ko.components.register('childComponent', {
 viewModel: component_vm,
 template: ...
})
```

Specify a factory function:

```
ko.components.register('childComponent', {
 viewModel: {
    createViewModel: function(params, componentInfo) {            
        return new component_vm(params, componentInfo);
    },
 template: ...
})
```

This then gives us access to componentInfo, from which we can fetch the binding context for the element the component is associated with:

```
function component_vm(params, componentInfo) {

 var parentContext = ko.contextFor(componentInfo.element).$parent;

 //anything available in the parent context is now available here
}
```

You can access any context in the chain using this approach all the way back to the root context without having to manually add anything to the parameters passed to each child.

Comment: This is an interesting approach but I think passing the parameters into the component form the parent is less coupled. Your way makes it harder to test.